# MPS file generation

Tags: optimization, matlab

I have a code in MATLAB which uses YALMIP to structure my optimization model and solve it via a solver. I would like to obtain a .mps file out of my model, apparently, YALMIP does not produce this if I am not mistaken. I would like to obtain a .mps file, how can I do this?

Edit: I know this is not an OR question, but I am sure a lot of OR people may face this challenge someday.

Comment: I think, this is an OR question :)

Comment: at least not theory :P

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in YALMIP but you may check the `saveampl(F,h,filename)` command written in YALMIP [website](https://yalmip.github.io/command/saveampl/). An example of the implementation is given as:

```
x = sdpvar(3,1);
A = randn(5,3);
b = randn(5,1);
c = randn(3,1);
F = [A*x <= b, integer(x(2:3))];
saveampl(F,c'*x,'myamplmodel.mod');
```

where I think you can save the model with `.mps` extension instead of `.mod`.

Comment: I think this is wrong since
``` saveampl exports a YALMIP model to an AMPL model. ```

Comment: @independentvariable, as I mentioned you may save it as .mps by changing .dat to .mps where the saveampl gives the option to mention the extension of your file in the command.